# AcquireTokenAsync expiring after 1 or 2 hours

Tags: c#, .net, azure-keyvault

I am trying to call AcquireTokenAsync it is working properly but after sometime it is not responding and it is not providing any result.

please refer the below code how to solve my issue

```
public static async Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

        if (result == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

        return result.AccessToken;
    }

    public static string GetKeyVaultSecret(string secretName)
    {
        try
        {
            var secretUri = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretUri"];
            var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetToken));
            var secret = kv.GetSecretAsync(secretUri, secretName).Result;
            return secret.Value;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if this is part of the problem but GetKeyVaultSecret() blocks an async call. It should be async and it should await GetSecretAsync.

Answer (score 0):

For access token, **the default time is 1 hour**. After 1 hour, the client must use the refresh token to (usually silently) acquire a new refresh token and access token.

You can change access token lifetime to the **maximum to one day** with this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/registration-config-change-token-lifetime-how-to).

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"24:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

For more details about token lifetime you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-types).

Comment: Hi can you please let me know how to refresh access token in c#

Comment: You can refer to this [article](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/05/30/refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api/).